# How to reset exercise counter in XSIM

Tags: xsim

How can I reset the exercise counter within the same exercise type. I don’t want to create different exercise types as I want to create question bank and use collection option. I have attached MWE and required output. I am beginner and I am open even if some one can improve my code by using XSIM.

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{tasks}


\settasks{
label = (\theexercise\arabic*) ,
label-width = 5ex,
item-indent=6ex
}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
  exercise-env = question ,
  solution-env = answer ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Answer ,
  exercise-template = item ,
  solution-template = solution ,
%   exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  counter = exercise, % shares a counter with the `exercise' type
}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]
  \GetExercisePropertyT{points}
    {%
    \marginpar
      {%
      \par\vspace{2.5ex plus .2ex}
      [\printgoal{\PropertyValue}]%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {}

     
  \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{solution}
  {\item[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]}
  {}


\newenvironment{questions}
   {\itemize}
   {\enditemize}

   \newenvironment{answers}
   {\itemize}
   {\enditemize}

\usepackage{lipsum}
    


\xsimsetup{
    exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}.,
    % exercise/within = section,
    % answer/print = true,
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Section A}

\begin{questions}

  \begin{question}[points=4]
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{answer}

  \begin{question}
    Answer the following questions.
    \begin{tasks}
      \task \lipsum[75]
      \task question.
    \end{tasks}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[75]
  \end{answer}



\end{questions}

\section*{Section B}


\begin{questions}

  \begin{question}[points=4]
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{answer}

  \begin{question}
    Answer the following questions.
    \begin{tasks}
      \task \lipsum[75]
      \task question.
    \end{tasks}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[75]
  \end{answer}


\end{questions}



% \begin{answers}
%   \item[] \printsolutions
% \end{answers}

\end{document}
```

Required output:

[image]

Comment: IMHO best would be to use numbered section `\section{…}` instead of `\section*{…}` and to use `\DeclareExerciseType` option `within=section`.

Comment: You use starred `\section*` macros which don't increase the `section` counter. Therefore linking the `exercise` counter to this counter has no effect at `\section*`. You could add  `\usepackage{xpatch} \xpretocmd{\section}{\setcounter{exercise}{0}}{}{}` to your preamble, but it is probably indeed better to use unstarred `\section` macros (as suggested in the comment above) and maybe hide the section number in some way.

Comment: Even if I use like this @JasperHabicht I am getting zero.Question number(0.1). I need to print only question number without section number.

Comment: @cabohah I have write an answer with your hint. I hope it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user *cabohah* has given the right direction to the solution in the comments.

After adding the setting `within=section` to `\DeclareExerciseType`, all you have to do is to redefine the `\section` command so that it doesn't display the number section at front of it. This can be do with the **titlesec** package, as showed.

In this solution, you are using the `\section` command, not the starred version `\section*`.

So, with this code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{tasks}

\settasks{
label = (\theexercise\arabic*) ,
label-width = 5ex,
item-indent=6ex
}

\DeclareExerciseType{question}{
  exercise-env = question ,
  solution-env = answer ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Answer ,
  exercise-template = item ,
  solution-template = solution ,
%   exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}. ,
  counter = exercise, % shares a counter with the `exercise' type
  within=section %% ADDED via comment by "cabohah"
}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{item}
  {\item[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]
  \GetExercisePropertyT{points}
    {%
    \marginpar
      {%
      \par\vspace{2.5ex plus .2ex}
      [\printgoal{\PropertyValue}]%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {}

     
  \DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{solution}
  {\item[\GetExerciseProperty{counter}]}
  {}


\newenvironment{questions}
   {\itemize}
   {\enditemize}

   \newenvironment{answers}
   {\itemize}
   {\enditemize}

\usepackage{lipsum}
    
\xsimsetup{
    exercise/the-counter = \arabic{exercise}.,
    %exercise/within = section,
    % answer/print = true,
}

% Modifying the \section command
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]%
{}%
{}%
{0pt}%
{\Large\textbf}%

\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\begin{questions}

  \begin{question}[points=4]
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{answer}

  \begin{question}
    Answer the following questions.
    \begin{tasks}
      \task \lipsum[75]
      \task question.
    \end{tasks}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[75]
  \end{answer}

\end{questions}


\section{Section B}

\begin{questions}

  \begin{question}[points=4]
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{answer}

  \begin{question}
    Answer the following questions.
    \begin{tasks}
      \task \lipsum[75]
      \task question.
    \end{tasks}
  \end{question}

  \begin{question}
    \lipsum[66]
  \end{question}
  \begin{answer}
    \lipsum[75]
  \end{answer}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

you obtain that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It worked perfectly. When I am using in xsimsetup I am not getting. I don't know why?

Comment: @Krishna I don't know enough about **xsim** and its internal mechanism to know if it is possible to get the same result with `\xsimsetup`. Moreover at the beginning of the **xsim** user manual it is stated that **xsim** is in an experimental state and actively developed, until it reaches a stable version.