# Resetting counter exercise for each page with Xsim package

Tags: xsim

I've seen this topic:[How to reset exercise counter in XSIM](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679798/how-to-reset-exercise-counter-in-xsim) but thats's not exactly what I want.
I am creating a document which contains exercices for my students.
Each page contains exercices for only one student and I would like to reset the counter of exercise after each new page.
It almost works with `\xsimsetup{exercise/within=page}` and (for each student):

```
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

The counter of exercise is reset with each page but the counter gives "Exercise 1.1", Exercise 1.2", on each page. So the first number is the number of the page, and the second number is the number of the exercise. I don't want "1.1", "1.2", but just "1", "2".
So how do I get rid off the number of the page.
While writing this, I wonder if maybe there is a command in the Xsim package which simply resets the counter of the page? If so, I could type this command after each `newpage` without considering the number of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, a simple `setcounter{exercise}{0}` works fine